# 1993 Jeep Cherokee tries to turn over but wont

Tags: starting, jeep, cherokee

It's like it floods every time. I have to put the gas to the floor in turn the key in order to get it running. I can let it run for however long and then turn it off. Then when I go to try to start it again it does the same thing it tries to turn over but it won't. Again I have to push the gas to the floor and turn the key to get it started. Any suggestions on what's wrong?

Comment: When was the last time the jeep was tuned up?

Comment: Which engine does it have? The 4 or 6 cylinder?

Answer (score 2):

**Interesting**

That vehicle has fuel injection via the throttle body.  It sounds like the engine is getting flooded, just like you said.  With IF (fuel injection) flooding has mostly become a thing of the past.

Since this vehicle may not have any interface to it's very rudimentary computer it can be hard to get diagnostic information out of it.  The fact you have to push the accelerator all the way to the floor to start it may be telling.

Perhaps your throttle body position sensor and/or the engine temperature sensors are having issues and the computer is injecting more fuel than you need to get the vehicle started.  It may be thinking the throttle position is not what it actually is or the computer thinks the engine is cold and therefor injecting MORE fuel than you need, which would happen with a choke on a cold morning in a carbureted vehicle.

Certainly, these are just thoughts a possibilities but I didn't see any answers so I thought that giving you something to think about for a task to test a couple of your sensors would be beneficial.

Perhaps someone could chime in and tear into my idea and poke some holes in it and offer more concrete thoughts and action items.